# Is there a way to set the next post ID to something very high?

Tags: php

I have two WooCommerce shops for the same client, one for the US and one for CAD.  We want to make sure there is no collision with respect to the order numbers on these two shops, so I want to set the next post ID on the CAD site to 900001 and then go from there (we don't get a lot of traffic).  Is there a way to do this without using a sequential order number plugin?  It seems I should just be able to create a post with this ID using the API and then the database will autoincrement from there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can increase the next post ID.

The next value is controlled by the *AUTO_INCREMENT* setting of the post table in your database.

If you use **phpMyAdmin**, you can do this by opening up the post table (my prefix is `wp1`, therefore my table here is `wp1_posts`), then select the "Operations" tab and then increase the value in the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

[image: phpmyAdmin increase auto increment value for post table in WordPress]

The alternative is doing this with an SQL query like:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp1_posts` AUTO_INCREMENT=900001
```

When I tried this out I ran into a small problem.
I got the error message:

> **#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date' posts**

I was able to solve it by first running the following query and then the query to increase the AUTO_INCREMENT value:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp1_posts` 
  CHANGE `post_date` `post_date`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CHANGE `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CHANGE `post_modified` `post_modified`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CHANGE `post_modified_gmt` `post_modified_gmt`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

That query is also necessary in case you use the "Operation" site in phpMyAdmin.

So first run it, then change the AUTO_INCREMENT setting.